# TextBox value not updated

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am fetching data from database to textbox using Linq.When i try update the same textbox value,it does not work.

```
DAL.TournamentsDataContext tdc = new SchoolSports.DAL.TournamentsDataContext();
        var tournamentTable = tdc.GetTable<DAL.Tournament>();
        var tournamentRecord = (from rec in tournamentTable
                                where rec.TournamentId == TournamentId
                                select rec).Single();           

        tournamentRecord.Tournament_type = Tournament_type;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_Name = Tournament_Name; ;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_Level = Tournament_Level;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_For = Tournament_For;
        tournamentRecord.Country_Code = Country_Code;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_Status = Tournament_Status;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_begin_date = Tournament_begin_date;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_end_date = Tournament_end_date;
        tournamentRecord.Sponsored_By = Sponsored_By;
        tournamentRecord.Tournament_Details = Tournament_Details;

        var organiserTable = tdc.GetTable<DAL.Organiser>();
        var organiserRecord = (from rec in organiserTable
                               where rec.Tournament_Id == TournamentId
                               select rec).Single();    
        organiserRecord.Name_Of_Organiser = OrName;
        organiserRecord.Telephone = OrTeleNo;
        organiserRecord.Email = OrEmail;
        organiserRecord.Mobile = OrMobile;
        organiserRecord.Fax = OrFax;

        if (Tournament_For == "School")
        {

            var invitedSchoolIdTable = tdc.GetTable<DAL.Invited_School>();
            var invitedSchoolIdRecord = (from rec in invitedSchoolIdTable
                                         where rec.Tournament_Id == TournamentId
                                         select rec).Single();
            invitedSchoolIdRecord.School_Ids = SchoolUniIds;

        }
        if (Tournament_For == "University")
        {

            var invitedUniversityTable = tdc.GetTable<DAL.Invited_University>();
            var invitedUniversityIdRecord = (from rec in invitedUniversityTable
                                             where rec.Tournament_Id == TournamentId
                                             select rec).Single();
            invitedUniversityIdRecord.University_Ids = SchoolUniIds;

        }
        tdc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: what are you using, linqtoXXX ?

Comment: linq-to-sql.Getting data from database and assign it to TextBox.On updating value in textbox,it remains unchanged.

Comment: I am not using DataGrid,Gridview or ListView.

Answer (score 0):

(The following answer was written before he updated the question)

If you want the value to be updated with the value in the text box, the text box must be bound to a datasource

Answer (score 0):

I have solved using IsPostBack in Page_Load Event.

Comment: Congrats , but you could've mentioned that its a webform app in your question.